# How to change IPython Notebook home directory?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I know that this question has already been asked but I didn't really achieve what I was looking for with the suggestions in the answers.
I'd like to change the default directory that IPython notebook uses when you open it from the terminal, since it shows hundreds of folders and it's impossible to choose the right one from there.

Comment: Can you explain why those mentioned answers did not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change to the desired directory **before** you start the IPython Notebook. On the terminal:

```
cd path/to/dir
```

and then:

```
ipython notebook
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was that easy >:

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.